# I made a very simple Pygame Zero game, but my Actor image and the screen.clear() is not working. Can you help me fix this?

Tags: python, pgzero

This is the full code for the very bad game example.

```
import pgzrun
from random import randint
from pgzero.builtins import Actor, animate, keyboard

apple = Actor('apple')

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    apple.draw()

def place_apple():
    apple.x = randint(10, 800)
    apple.y = randint(10, 600)

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    if apple.collidepont(pos):
        print("Good shot!")
        place_apple()
    else:
        print("You missed!")
        quit()

place_apple()
pgzrun.go()
```

the screen.clear() isn't working and apple = actor("apple") also isn't working. I have no idea why. Please help me!

Comment: [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is not [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news). You have to use the [tag:pgzero] tag instead of the [tag:pygame] tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from pgzero.actor import Actor
from pgzero.keyboard import keyboard
```

not sure if it helps.

Are you using mu editor or pycharm ??

Do you have an apple image in the correct path ?

Answer (score 0):

i tried the same instructions and found that adding the import pygame solved the issue.

```
import pgzrun
from random import randint
import pygame

WIDTH  = 800
HEIGHT = 600
pig = Actor('pig')
schaap = Actor('schaap')
zombie = Actor('zombie')
konijn = Actor('konijn')

def draw():    
    screen.clear
    screen.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    pig.draw()
    schaap.draw()
    zombie.draw()
    konijn.draw()

def plaats_pig():    
    pig.x = randint(10,800)
    pig.y = randint(10,600)

def plaats_schaap():    
    schaap.x = randint(20,800)
    schaap.y = randint(20,600)

def plaats_zombie():    
    zombie.x = randint(70,800)
    zombie.y = randint(70,600)

def plaats_konijn():    
    konijn.x = randint(100,800)
    konijn.y = randint(100,600)


def on_mouse_down(pos):
    if pig.collidepoint(pos):
        sounds.schiet.play()    
        plaats_pig()
    elif schaap.collidepoint(pos):
        sounds.schiet.play()    
        plaats_schaap()
    elif zombie.collidepoint(pos):
        sounds.schiet.play()    
        plaats_zombie()
    elif konijn.collidepoint(pos):
        sounds.schiet.play()    
        plaats_konijn()
    else:
        sounds.mis.play()
        print('lekker puhh, mis')  
    

plaats_pig()
plaats_schaap()
plaats_zombie()
plaats_konijn()
pgzrun.go()
```